# dynamic add Discriminator Map inheritance mapping doctrine 2

Tags: inheritance, doctrine-orm

i have parent class with inheritance mapping

```
/**
 * Product
 *
* @Entity(repositoryClass="ProductRepository") 
* @Table(name="tbl_product")
* @InheritanceType("JOINED")
* @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="integer")
* @DiscriminatorMap({ 0 = "Product", 1 = "Bag"})
*/
class Product 
{
```

how can add new product type like shoes dynamically into "DiscriminatorMap"

thanks

Comment: I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4622#issuecomment-162368673) but haven't gotten it to work (yet).

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/jasperkuperus/03302fefe6e4722ab650) should also be able to help out future finders of this question. I'll try to dig in and answer this question with it in the future, for now going a different route.